# how to externalize the entities in jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am creating data API JARs using JPA.

Currently onshore team has not finalize the table structure, there may be some changes in the structure of the tables.

So is there any way that I can put all my entities outside of the JAR and JPA will automatically take the change in Entites from outside?

Comment: are you using spring or plain Hibernate?

Comment: I am using spring boot and JPA by hibernate..

Comment: are you deploying a runnable jar or a war in a app server?

Comment: we will deploy runnable jar ....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to experiment with loader.path and add the directory where your external classes are compiled to:

```
java -Dloader.path="build" -jar YourSpringApp.jar
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features

It's important that you configure that PropertiesLauncher is in the MANIFEST.MF to launch your application.